# Facebook javascript API get users photos one at the time

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello i am trying to get the users tagged photos one at the time with javascript.

Here is how i call it:

```
 FB.api('/me?fields=name,picture.type(large),photos.limit(2).type(tagged)', function(response) {
  play(response.name, response.picture.data.url, response.photos.data.source);
   ....
```

And how i use them:

```
 use:  {url: "some url....", params: ['name','fb','photo1', 'photo2']},
```

The thing is that when i call this i get "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined "

on the photos.limit(2).type(tagged)

The other things work great. Name and profile pic.

Any ideas?

Perhaps i need to sort the results from photos.limit(2).type(tagged) or something but i have no clue o how to do that...

Any help will be awesome.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you aren't getting any data from the photos endpoint.

Ensure that you have `user_photos` permission in

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'user_photos'});
```

Comment: Ah..Of course. 
But now i get like 1000 oath dialogs opening like a thunderstorm. Any ideas on what that is? 

If you like to add me on skype to get the link to the page i am working on pls do so. Skype id: appforcon